# Spanish Text in PHP WHILE loop from MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, utf-8

Hey: I'm trying to display data from a MySQL database in an HTML table. However, some of the text is in Spanish and the special characters are showing up as �. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Database import script db.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
// Enter your Host, username, password, database below.
// I left password empty because i do not set password on localhost.
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","yamanagolddb");
// Check connection
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

Table display script table.php:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
require('db.php');
include("auth.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>View Records</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form">
<p><a href="index.php">Home</a> 
| <a href="insert.php">Insert New Record</a> 
| <a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p>
<h2>View Records</h2>
<table width="100%" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th><strong>S.No</strong></th>
<th><strong>Hecho Por</strong></th>
<th><strong>Nombre</strong></th>
<th><strong>CÓDIGO</strong></th>
<th><strong>INFLUENCIA</strong>&#13;&#10;(1) Sin influencia a (5) Influencia maxima</th>
<th><strong>POSTURA</strong>&#13;&#10;(1) Apoyo activo a (5) Oposicion activa</th>
<th><strong>CREDIBILIDAD</strong>&#13;&#10;(1) Sin credibilidad a (5) Credibilidad Maxima</th>
<th><strong>ACCESIBILIDAD</strong>&#13;&#10;(1) Alta disposicon a dialogar a (5) Sin disposicion a dialogar</th>
<th><strong>Fecha</strong></th>
<th><strong>Edit</strong></th>
<th><strong>Delete</strong></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
$count=1;
$sel_query="Select * from surveydata ORDER BY 'jectid' desc;";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sel_query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
<tr><td align="center"><?php echo $count; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo html_entity_decode($row["hecho_por"]); ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["pi_nbre"]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["id_nombre"]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["pi_influenc"]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["pi_posicio"]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["pi_credib"]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["pi_acces"]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["fecha_actu"]; ?></td>
<td align="center">
<a href="edit.php?jectid=<?php echo $row["jectid"]; ?>">Edit</a>
</td>
<td align="center">
<a href="delete.php?jectid=<?php echo $row["jectid"]; ?>">Delete</a>
</td>
</tr>
<?php $count++; } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the html parts, if I add a Spanish word with special characters they display correctly. For example, **CÓDIGO** displays correctly. However, the data pulled from the database shows special characters as �.

Comment: Set the character set on the connection, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php.

Comment: You could also check that your table.php file have the desirable encoded charset.

Comment: Also `'jectid'` should be encapsulated with backticks, as is that is a string, not a column.

Comment: also set the language in the html (=es)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: @RachelGallen I thought UTF8 encompassed spanish characters. Where does the `es` need to be set?

Comment: Set lang=es in the html tag

Comment: Thanks user3783243, that site worked perfectly. Thanks everyone else for the tips as well - my first time using PHP was about 48 hours ago so I'm still quite new to it.

Comment: See "black diamond" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored